# Find biggest cluster in a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have to find a cluster in a 2d array. That means i have to find the biggest amount of "1" in a 2d array. There are just "0" and "1" in the array. Connected numbers could be all "1" in each direction (8 directions) 
for example this matrix has a cluster of 6

Example:  Output = 6

```
ma[] = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0, 0,    //because of diagonal
         0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };   // the last "1" should not be counted
```

Unfotunately i have no idea how to do that. Here is my latest code with which i can just count all "1" in the 2d array.

```
void cluster(int *mat, int rows, int cols) { 
    int i, j;
    int target = 0;
    printf("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\nbiggst cluster\n\n");
    for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) { 
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (mat[j*rows+i] == 1)
        target = target + 1;
        }
    }
printf("%d ", target);
}
```

I really would appreciate a small code or an algorithm to solve this problem.

Greets

Comment: Look up "flood fill"

Comment: Are you just trying to count all 1's in your array?

Comment: @Rizier123 no i want to find the biggest connected amount of "1" please look again at the example

Comment: @Dmitri isn't it extremely dangerous to use such a recursive algorithm?

Comment: More specifically then, scanline fill

Comment: why not run dfs taking matrix as a graph having vertices where only 1 is present and a edge is present between horizontal vertical and diagonal vertex having 1 and just find the connected component that has maximum vertices

Comment: i would really appreciate a small code guys..

Comment: @WirJun, here you are -- but you *will* have to tinker with it a bit ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be approached by first defining and stating the objectives, then breaking it into the steps necessary to solve:

First, some clarifications of your problem statement:

The following ***does not define a 2D matrix***, it is created as a single dimension array with 20 elements

```
ma[] = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 0, 0,    //because of diagonal
         0, 1, 0, 0, 1 };   // the last "1" should not be counted
```

*the biggest amount of "1" in a 2d array*
***Assume you mean***, *number of adjacent elements with value == 1* in the array
***And***
*numbers could be all "1" in each direction (8 directions)*
There are really ***only two directions in a C array***.  (See below for explanation)

For clarity, modify some definitions:
1) define a cluster of values:
   a cluster is 1 or more array elements that contain the value 1, and are *adjacent* to another array element in any direction. (see comments on *adjacent* below)
2) define a 2D array in C:
   A 2D array in C is an area of contiguous memory where array elements are arranged in row major fashion:

```
Example: int array[4][5] = {{1,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0}};
```

Conceptually looks like this:

```
|1|0|0|0|0|    
|0|1|0|0|0|     
|0|0|1|0|0|    
|0|0|0|1|0|  //cluster of four
```

But in memory looks like this:

```
|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|  //cluster of zero  (no "1" elements next to another)
|         |         |         |       |              
[0][0]    [1][0]    [2][0]    [3][0]  [3][4]
```

Note that in reality, *Adjacent* takes on a different perspective.

So the *intended* solution has little to do with adjacent memory, and more to do with array notation, e.g. `[i][j]`.

For your purpose then, *adjacent* should be defined as:
proximity of an element's indices, where another element is at most 1 index away in any direction:

Given int `array[ROWS][COLS];`

***Here is a test for adjacency***: (using our definition)

`array[m][n]` is adjacent to `array[o][p]` when:

- `!((m == o) && (n == p))  //same element`
- `(abs(m - o) <= 1) && (abs(n-p) <= 1)`
- `((m + o) < ROWS) &&((n + p) < COLS)`

The problem can be solved by traversing all elements, row by row, and at each element, testing for proximity to another element by looking at each surrounding index.

Comment: +1 for noticing that is not actually a matrix. I hadn't examined the code closely :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are more memory-efficient methods, but: you can build another matrix with the same size and initialize it to all zeroes. Let this matrix be B.

Start scanning first matrix, A, with a counter N initialized to 1, and as soon as you find in A a "1" that has a "0" in B (i.e. Aij = 1, Bij = 0), put it into a list and initialize M to 0.

Then until the list is empty:

- pop an item from the list and increment M.
- look at its neighbours (you only need (x-1, y), (x+1, y), (y+1, x-1), (y+1, x) and (y+1, x+1) ) and if they have Ax'y' = 1 and Bx'y' = 0, set Bx'y' to N and add them to the list.

When the list is empty, you have found M elements in cluster N, so set `ClusterSize[N]=M`.

When you finish, find the maximum value of ClusterSize, suppose this is ClusterSize[K]; then all elements where Bij = K belong to a cluster of cardinality M.

The algorithm visits once all matrix items. You need at most W * H/4 elements for the Cluster array (you can't have more than W * H/4 1-item clusters without some items connecting and decreasing the number of clusters), at most W * H for AncillaryMatrix, and W * H items for List. You can dynamically allocate and reallocate them at will, but unless necessary to save memory, I'd just go with the pessimistic value.

Pseudo code:

```
int **AncillaryMatrix;

if (NULL == (AncillaryMatrix = malloc(sizeof(int *)*H))) {
    return ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
}
for (j = 0; j < H; j++) {
    if (NULL == (AncillaryMatrix[j] = malloc(sizeof(int)*W))) {
        while (--j) {
             free(AncillaryMatrix[j]); AncillaryMatrix[j] = NULL;
        }
        free(AncillaryMatrix); AncillaryMatrix = NULL;
        return ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        AncillaryMatrix[j][i] = 0;
    }
}
N = 1;
for (j = 0; j < H; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < W; i++) {
        if (0 == BaseMatrix[j][i]) {
            continue;
        }
        if (0 != AncillaryMatrix[j][i]) {
            continue;
        }
        if (0 == (Cluster[N] = FillMatrix(BaseMatrix, AncillaryMatrix, W, H, i, j, N)) {
            // Handle out of memory error.
        }
        N++;
    }
}
// Free ancillarymatrix, unless you need to know the items in the K-th cluster
j = H; while (j--) {
     free(AncillaryMatrix[j]); AncillaryMatrix[j] = NULL;
}
free(AncillaryMatrix); AncillaryMatrix = NULL;

// Find maximum value in Cluster[1..N-1].
// Cluster[0] is not used because "0" in AncillaryMatrix means "no cluster here"
// So the number of clusters is really N-1.
for (j = 1, i = 2; i < N; i++) {
     if (Cluster[i] > Cluster[j]) {
         j = i;
     }
}
// Largest cluster identified by j, has Cluster[j] members.

////

int FillMatrix(int **B, int **A, int W, int H, int i, int j, int N) {
    int M = 0;
    typedef struct Item { int x, int y } *List;
    if (null == (List = malloc(sizeof(Item)*W*H))) {
         return 0;
    }
    List[l].x = i;
    List[l].y = j;
    A[j][i] = N;
    l++;
    while (l) {
        l--; M++;
        int ii = List[l].x;
        int jj = List[l].y;
        // Add neighbours. NOTE: add code to handle case when jj or ii is 0
        // or jj is H-1 or ii is W-1.

        // check jj,ii-1 (could use a macro)
        if (B[jj][ii-1]) {
            if (0 == A[jj][ii-1]) {
                List[l].x = ii-1;
                List[l].y = jj;
                l++;
            }
        }
        CHECK(jj, ii+1)
        CHECK(jj+1, ii-1)
        CHECK(jj+1, ii)
        CHECK(jj+1, ii+1)
    }
    free(List); // List = NULL;
    return M;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I just started practicing the language C 2 months ago and I'm really wondering how someone like me should solve such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have finally found a really easy solution for this problem just look here...

```
void cluster(int rows, int cols) { 

    int ma4[4][5] = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 1. Zeile
                     {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, // 2. Zeile
                     {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, // 3. Zeile
                     {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}};  // 4. Zeile
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int target = 0;
    printf("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\nbiggst cluster\n\n");
    for(j = 0; j < cols; j++) { 
        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (ma4[j][i] == 1) {
        if (ma4[j-1][i] || ma4[j][i-1] || ma4[j+1][i] || ma4[j][i+1] || ma4[j-1][i-1] || ma4[j+1][i+1] || ma4[j-1][i+1] || ma4[j+1][i-1] == 1)
           target += 1;
            }
        }


    }
printf("%d ", target);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is going to work if, say, the bottom right item is 1? You will be reading outside the matrix itself.